# merge objective c project and objective c++ project

Tags: c++, objective-c

is it possible to merge objective c project with c++ project aurioTouchhttp://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because: There is no such thing as an "Objective-C project" or "Objective-C++ project", there are just projects that contain source files.

You can mix Obj-C, Obj-C++, C, and C++ source files all in one project, and (in general) Xcode will do the right thing. Do you have a specific problem?